# ZIP Deployment to Azure Web App fails when triggered from GitHub Actions workflow due to Storage Limitations

Tags: .net, azure, github-actions

I have an F1-tier ASP with a single Web App, and I'm trying to deploy to that web app using a GH Actions workflow. The workflow itself is pretty cookie-cutter; it uses the `Deploy a .NET Core app to an Azure Web App` template from GitHub with only minor modifications. The workflow has worked well in the past, but is now failing and giving me the following error message in the Deployment Center:

`Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file. There is not enough space on the disk.`

I've looked at similar questions that seems to suggest that the issue is due to a ZIP deployment being attempted without deleting the previous ZIP file, which does *not* seem to be true in my case, but even so I've looked at the ASP File System Storage and it's nowhere near its limit. Even if I were to deploy this ZIP without the old one being deleted, it'd still not even be half-way to capacity. I assume the storage limitation is not on the ASP, but somewhere else?

Stranger still is that I can run a deployment directly from Visual Studio and I never seem to encounter this issue. I'm deploying the same application to the same Web App, so how can storage be an issue in one case, but not another? Even a ZIP deployment from VS will go through without issue.

I could perhaps clear space manually in Kudu, but I don't want to have to do this every time I want to deploy.

I'm scratching my head a little on this, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share your GitHub repository link if possible.

Comment: I'm afraid it's a private repo, so I can't provide a link.